# How to load tableview dynamically in swift 4

Tags: swift, tableview

[image]I have used Worm Tab Strip cocoapod to get tabs like android, the name of tabs are from server response, I need n number of view controllers based on the number of tab names.

For testing purpose, I have hardcoded tab names, and for each particular tab name, I have another array of sub names. My question is how do I change the tableview contents so that, I get an exact number of sub names according to the tab names

```
var tabNames = ["Brands", "Sports","Movies", "Mobile","Games"]
var brandsNames = ["Addidas", "Nike","Puma"]
var sportsName = ["Cricket","Fifa","Hockey","Baseball"]
var moviesName = ["Mission Impossible","Matrix","Avatar","Titanic"]
var mobileNames = ["Nokia","Redmi","Samsung"]
var gameNames = ["FIFA 19","PES 19","WWE 2K19","Max Payne"]
```

What should i try in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {

   // return fruits.count
    }
```

And

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
for: indexPath) as! Cell1
    //cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]

    return cell
    }
```

I need to get for Brands tab, I need brandsNames as tableview 
    contents.

The tableview contents must change according to the tab names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I used this [enter link description here](https://medium.com/swift-india/android-like-tabs-in-ios-sliding-tabs-segments-4dc38d801463) as a reference So that I can pass ID of particular tab to tableview in viewcontroller and load that Tablview, So now I can dynamically add new tabs and the corresponding Tablview also changes

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom  struct as data model for example

```
struct Category {  
    let name : String
    let items : [String]
}
```

Declare a data source array and an index

```
var categories = [Category]()
var index = 0
```

In `viewDidLoad` populate the data source array and set `index` of the current index of the `UISegmentedControl`

```
categories = [Category(name:"Brands", items: ["Addidas", "Nike","Puma"]),
              Category(name:"Sports", items: ["Cricket","Fifa","Hockey","Baseball"]),
              Category(name:"Movies", items: ["Mission Impossible","Matrix","Avatar","Titanic"]),
              Category(name:"Mobile", items: ["Nokia","Redmi","Samsung"]),
              Category(name:"Games", items: ["FIFA 19","PES 19","WWE 2K19","Max Payne"])]

index = // current index of the segmented control
```

in the `IBAction` of the segmented control set the index and reload the table view

```
@IBAction func categorySelection(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The data source methods are

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return categories[index].items.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
    cell.textLabel?.text = categories[index].items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sir, I actually I'm not using segmented control, I will get the id of the selected tab from that Warm Tab cocoapod, so based on the id how to reload tableview

Comment: I don't know this library but I guess there is a property which indicates the index and an action which is called when the user changes the tab. Just use those.

Comment: Sir is there any solution like having only one viewcontroller and changing its contents based on the selected tab-id

Comment: Sir, I used the below method and I got the Results